# Next13 server component rendered twice with getStaticParams

Tags: reactjs, next.js

the following code renders my Server Component twice. Steps for reproduction:

1. Add the code below in `app/test/[id]/page.tsx`

```js
export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return [{ id: "1" }, { id: "2" }]
}

async function Component({ params }) {
  const { id } = params

  console.log("id: ", id)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Component</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Component
```

2. Generate build with => `yarn build`
3. Start production build => `yarn start`
4. Go to the route `test/1` (1 is just a random param)

You will see that the component is rendered twice ("id: 1" printed twice).
Is this an expected behaviour of Nextjs13, a bug or is there a way to avoid rendering 2 times the component?

Comment: [maybe because of React 18 strict mode](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/35822)

Comment: @boop_the_snoot react strict mode is only active in development mode. As you can see in the steps I am generating the production build :)

Comment: ah right, that was a brain fart. :D